# continuing eval saga: how to eval printf a single quote

Tags: bash

Thank you to all for previous two answers to eval.  As I get more complex, the previous answers no longer suffice, so here goes again

By the last advice, I have to use a construct like this

```
bash> eval "printf $foo"
```

The problem is, what if

```
bash> foo="'"

bash eval "printf $foo"
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Now, I cannot change the way foo is assigned.  I cannot escape ' there or some such.  The first line has to stay.  Also, in the second line I have to have eval and I have to quote the whole thing - that has to stay so the previous advices are still working.

Now, how to get the second line to print??

Comment: It may be better if you show what you really want to do. I don't think anything can be a perfect or non-hacky solution for that. Your `$foo` can have characters with special meanings.

Comment: `bash` may simply be the wrong tool for what you're trying to do. It simply doesn't have good facilities for quoting and escaping text properly. Where are you getting these strings from, and why are you trying to use them with `eval`?

Comment: Do you have an actual use case in mind, or are you just exploring the limits of `eval`? Generally speaking, you can avoid nearly all uses of `eval`; it only exists for extreme corner cases (more so in `bash` than in POSIX `sh`, since `bash` introduces some specific features, like indirect parameter expansions, that require `eval` in `sh`.)

Comment: yes I have an actual case, but it is much larger.  Yes I am thinking of moving the whole thing to Python if it gets a little more complex.  I am just trying to give you an SSCCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "printf $foo"      # printf '
```

Of course, this won't work. You need quotes - just as you needed one when you assigned the variable.

```
eval "printf \"$foo\""  # executing printf "'"
```

Be aware that this is not a generic solution though:

```
foo='"'
eval "printf \"$foo\""  # executing printf """
```

The generic rule, don't use eval applies here. Considering you're struggling with some "basic" concepts, I would say, doubly so.

Answer (score 0):

Questions with arbitrary, contrived restrictions are really more suited for the [programming puzzle exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), but I'll play.

To summarize the rules:

1. The assignment of `foo` has to stay
2. The `eval` has to stay.
3. The argument to eval has to be exactly one double quoted string, with the contents of your choice.
4. The end result should be to print the contents of the variable foo (?)

That's simple enough. Just quote the parameter expansion so that it's done during eval rather than before:

```
foo="'"
eval "printf \"%s\n\" \"\$foo\""
```

This works regardless of the value of `foo`, be it single quotes, double quotes or anything else.

PS: If you're trying to figure out how to build an argument for a tool that uses `sh -c`, you need to ask about that instead.

Comment: pardon me, but these are not "contived restrictions" at all!  This is real programming, real application, where I have certain restrictions to accomplish other effects, and now I need to have another effect, but I don't want to undo what already works.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is exactly what shell-safe representations of strings are for.  Use `printf '%q'` to convert `foo` into a shell-safe representation:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

declare foo="'"
printf -v shell_safe_foo '%q' "${foo}"

eval "printf ${shell_safe_foo}"
```

outputs:

```
'
```

Verify that various forms of command injection trickery don't work with this approach:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

declare foo='${USER} $(whoami) `ls -al`'
printf -v shell_safe_foo '%q' "${foo}"

eval "printf ${shell_safe_foo}"
```

outputs:

```
${USER} $(whoami) `ls -al`
```